# How to install bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using qubes (based on Fedora 25) that comes without bluetooth out of the box. Well I need to install it. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your DE?

Blueman is pretty reliable.
Check out Blueman and Blueman-applet if you want a tray icon.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Blueman#Blueman

Comment: What is DE and how to install blueman?

Comment: DE is a desktop environment. You install packages using your system's package manager. I believe Fedora currently uses `dnf` so you'd do something like `dnf install blueman`

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me!
I believe it is with xfce

Comment: Okay, that doesn't really change anything in this case. use `dnf install blueman` and `blueman-applet` If you run the application `blueman-applet` then you should see an applet in your DE. It'll be on the xfce bar.

Comment: I finally installed it but it doesn't really work for some reason.
https://ibb.co/fkaZUb

Comment: Please use `scrot` and post your screenshot. I need to see your whole shell. run buleman-applet in terminal. any errors?